# Office 2010 on 14.04 under wine?

Tags: 14.04, wine, microsoft-office

How do I run Office 2010 on Ubuntu 14.04 under wine? While Libre Office opens many files not all are readable.

Comment: Have you tried to do it yet?

Comment: There's also WPS Office for Linux that claims to be 100% MS Office compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wine HQ, neither the 64-bit or 32-bit of Office 2010 or Office 2013 can be run on Ubuntu. The 32-bit of 2010 will install, but will be unable to activate. The 64-bit version of 2010 won't even be able to install. Both editions of 2013 will have the same problem as 2010 64-bit. You either need to look for alternatives, such as Office 365 or make a Windows virtual machine.

EDIT:

It seems that there is a possibility to get Office 2010 running with Wine. You'll only get Word, Excel and PowerPoint, though. Follow this link at start at step 2: http://www.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1885051

Answer (score 2):

Office 2010 works fine under Wine as long as you install first "playonlinux" package.

1. Install playonlinux
2. start playonlinux
3. install - office - office 2010

This should do it

Comment: Do we have confirmation?