# how to install microsoft office 2010 in ubuntu 14.04 without playonlinux or wine

Tags: 14.04

I can't install microsoft Office 2010 or 2007 with Wine or Playonlinux.

Is there another way to install?

Thank for your help

Comment: Use a VM like Virtualbox or VMWare to install Windows and then install Office inside that. Now a days you can even use the [online](https://www.office.com/) version of Office tools instead of installing it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Office 2010 on 14.04 under wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/610773/office-2010-on-14-04-under-wine)

Comment: This can do done (Office 2010 on 14.04), but has limitations and requires some effort.

Comment: You should try WPS Office (http://wps-community.org/), the Linux version is still in alpha but this program is better than Microsoft Office.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an MS Office *compatible* package, there are several versions available that are near 100% compatible, e.g. LibreOffice, version 4.2+ is available in the Ubuntu Software Center as 'LibreOffice'
*(Make sure to select exactly that, not single applications)*

Alternatively https://www.libreoffice.org/ has an all new *(at the time of writing)* version 5.0+, but that version is likely to require some manual work to install.
*(This is likely to appear as an update in the Ubuntu Software Center as verified to be working in Ubuntu - allow some time)*

If you need to have EXACTLY "MS Office" your remaining alternative is to install Windows in a "Virtual Machine"
*(Install Virtualbox or VMWare first, then present a Windows install disk to it, progress to install software as usual)*

Answer (score 0):

Native Microsoft Office won't work on linux natively.

If you have a Microsoft Windows License, go just ahead and install it in virtualbox and on it your office suite.

If you don't own a Microsoft Windows License , you'll have to use wine or playonlinux as abstraction layer to work with Microsoft Office.